# article style bibliography in Beamer class

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, beamerposter

I'm making a poster with the `beamer` class and the `beamerposter` package. I add some important references at the end, but I don't like the style. I would like the style that a bibliography has in the `article` class. is there a way to do this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Baird2002,
author = {Baird, Kevin M and Hoffmann, Errol R and Drury, Colin G},
journal = {Applied ergonomics},
month = jan,
number = {1},
pages = {9--14},
title = {{The effects of probe length on Fitts' law.}},
volume = {33},
year = {2002}
}
\end{filecontents}

%\usetheme{EastLansing}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
% make bibliography entries smaller
%\renewcommand\bibfont{\scriptsize}
% If you have more than one page of references, you want to tell beamer
% to put the continuation section label from the second slide onwards
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]
% Now get rid of all the colours
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
% and kill the abominable icon
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{My great slide}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \cite{baird2002} said some stuff.
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How many entries do you have? Is manual entry feasible?

Comment: Could you get more precise on "don't like the style"? Do you mean the style of the references, meaning which information is presented and what order? Or do you mean the formatting (text color and stuff)?

Comment: @ percube in this case it would be possible, but with future use in mind i would like a better solution

Comment: @ Benedikt Bauer I don't like the formatting. the standard style in beamer places the authors, title and journal all on separate lines and it uses bullets and colors. I want it more plain like you would get with \bibliographystyle{newapa}
in the article class

Comment: @jelle [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: if you precede a user name _directly_ with an `@` (like I just did with yours) the user gets notified about your comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I agree with you that the default Beamer bibliography format is (shall we say) not ideal and bordering on the garish.  Here's what I use, which gets you a pretty standard bibliography.  Please note that this solution uses the `natbib` package, since the `apalike.bst` file is designed to be used with it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}

@article{Sag1985,
    Author = {Ivan A Sag and G Gazdar and T Wasow and S Weisler},
    Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    Pages = {117-171},
    Title = {Coordination and How to Distinguish Categories},
    Volume = {3},
    Year = {1985}}
\end{filecontents}

\usetheme{EastLansing}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
% make bibliography entries smaller
\renewcommand\bibfont{\scriptsize}
% If you have more than one page of references, you want to tell beamer
% to put the continuation section label from the second slide onwards
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]
% Now get rid of all the colours
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry location}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
% and kill the abominable icon
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{My great slide}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \cite{Sag1985,Saussure1995} said some stuff.
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: thanks, but this only solves part of my problem. I could not get your code to work, I keep getting that there are undifined citations. but by inserting the beamercolors and the beamertemplate for the bibliography item, the text went black and I lost the item symbol. however the author name, title and journal are still all on different lines whereas I want them to be like in the output you gave. any ideas

Comment: I added a minimum working example to my original post to show my problem

Comment: @jelle You commented out the `\usepackage{natbib}`.  Add that back in and the example works.

Comment: for some reason natbib gave me an error. I googled it and apparently I just need to define \newblock. I found   \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em} and that seems to solve it.