# References don't show up on beamer poster package

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, beamerposter

I had generated a beamer poster in portrait mode and was able to generate references as expected. Due to conference requirements, I edited the poster to be in landscape mode but I am unable to generate the references with exactly same piece of code. I tried following advice like using `filecontents package` as shown in [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97615/article-style-bibliography-in-beamer-class), [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464434/references-bibliography-in-beamer). I have the following piece of relevant code. I don't see anything related to bib in log or in the mactex console. Please advice!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.30,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{random_projection,
  title={Near-optimal signal recovery from random projections: Universal encoding strategies?},
  author={Candes, Emmanuel J and Tao, Terence},
  journal={IEEE transactions on information theory},
  volume={52},
  number={12},
  pages={5406--5425},
  year={2006},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\title{}
\author[]{}
\institute[]{}

\begin{document}
\def\cwidth{0.30\textwidth}



\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.9\linewidth}

\begin{block}{References}
\nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{block}

\end{column}        
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your example doesn't contain any citation. So why do you expect to get something in the references?

Comment: citations.bib contains my references. I also verified my citations using bibtex everything looks fine.

Comment: it is not enough to have a bib, you must also cite some entries with \cite{key} or \nocite{key}.

Comment: I did \nocite{*} in the body. Sorry I didn't add all the changes I made because I followed different paths to achieve the result (I added the `fileconntents` path here).

Comment: there is no \nocite in your code. And after your edits it errors with `! Undefined control sequence. \addbibresource` as you don't load biblatex.

Comment: Ok let me make it working example with the same result.

Comment: So I added biblatex package and added nocite{*} to my body but I still don't see any references being printed.

Comment: did you run biber? Can you show the content of the `.blg` file?

Comment: I ran biber on the file before pdflatex and voila it works! Thanks for your input.

Sorry, I didn't know I need to run biber before running pdflatex

Comment: I don't know how to upvote your comments but +1, thanks for the help!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So this does not exactly pertain to the question but originally, I ran my poster tex file in potrait mode without nocite, biber, or biblatex using just \bibliography{file.bib} but it still worked. Do you have any insight on why that might have worked?